# How can I solve when playing the video on Android phone that request accept-encoding : gzip,defalte,sdch

Tags: android, node.js, google-chrome, video, request-headers

I'm developing a web application with **node.js**.

When I play a video using Chrome on the desktop, it works fine. But when using Chrome on an Android phone, the video doesn't play. I've noticed in the request header that the value for `accept-encoding` is different.

How can I get this video to play on an Android phone?

Here's the request headers when playing the video in Chrome on the desktop:

```
{ 
  host              : ----------- ,
  connection        : 'keep-alive',
  'accept-encoding' : 'identity;q=1, *;q=0',
  'user-agent'      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36',
  accept            : '*/*',
  referer           : 'http:// ----------- /present',
  'accept-language' : 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
  cookie            : 'PHPSESSID=sfccbv32oceu91gdedikukag07',
  range             : 'bytes=0-' 
}
```

And here's the request headers when playing the video in Chrome on Android:

```
{ 
  host              : ----------- ,
  connection        : 'keep-alive',
  'user-agent'      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; **Android 4.1.2**; IM-A830L Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.99 **Mobile** Safari/537.36',
  accept            : '*/*',
  referer           : 'http:// ---------- /oudience',
  'accept-encoding' : 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
  'accept-language' : 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' 
}
```

Comment: probably has more to do with Range than accept-encoding...

Comment: Second request headers not include 'Range'... Doesn't matter adding 'Range' in request headers  ??

Comment: after thinking about it more, i realized there are dozens of reasons why a video would play on the desktop but not on mobile, headers probably don't have anything to do with it. After all, some videos play on chrome mobile, whatever it's doing...

Comment: I go through with play a video in chrome on Android phone.  I compress video file to gzip  and  add resopnse.writeHead(200,{'content-encoding':'gzip'}) and response.end( 'compress_file');

Comment: any update on this.  Face similar issue, only on Chrome on Android.  Firefox on Android works.  Video plays in Chrome/Android when source references the file directly on the file system but as soon as it is requested thru the handler it does not work.  I tried to GZip it, doesn't work.  Have 206 range in the handler but Chrome/Android seems to request the same start and end chunk like 'Range: 16564-16563'